# How can I retrieve a service account OAuth2 token from Google Api with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I need to use a google projects service account to access google API using JavaScript. In order to do this I need to OAuth2 to google API servers to get an auth token.

I understand that Google provides a library (GAPI) for use on node servers, but I need a solution that will work in other secure JavaScript environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two major divisions to this task.

1. Configuring
2. Coding

First the **Configuration** steps.

- If you don't have a google account:

  1. Navigate to [google.com](http://google.com)
  2. Find and Click  "Sign In"
  3. Click "More Options"
  4. Click "Create Account"
  5. Follow the steps to create an account
- Navigate to the api dashboard: [console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard)
- Select or create a project by clicking on the current project. The project I have showing is called "My Project" [image]
- Click [image: google enable apis and services] and enable those API you plan to work with
- navigate to the credentials section: [console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
- Click [image: google create credentials] and select "Service account key"

  - If you create a new service account, for testing set the role to  "project" "owner". You'll want to read up on google Api roles eventually. See [Managing Roles](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-roles) and [Granting Roles to Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts)
- Ensure "Key Type" is "Json" and click "Create". You're key/cert will automatically download

Now for the **Coding** portion.

- First download [jsrsasign](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign) and add reference to "jsrsasign-all-min.js". If you want you can download just "jsrsasign-all-min.js" from github
- Second update the following script with your cert/key (downloaded earlier):

  ```
  function postJWT(jwt, callback) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == 4) {
              if (this.status == 200 && callback) {
                  callback(this.responseText);
                  return;
              }
              if (console) console.log(this.responseText);
          }
      };
      var parameters = "grant_type=" + encodeURIComponent("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer") + "&assertion=" + encodeURIComponent(jwt);
      xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send(parameters);
  }

  function getCert() {
      var cert = //your json key (downloaded earlier) goes here
          {
              "type": "service_account",
              "project_id": "proj..",
              "private_key_id": "e18..",
              "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII..==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
              "client_email": "service-account@...iam.gserviceaccount.com",
              "client_id": "5761..",
              "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
              "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
              "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
              "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/..service-account%40...iam.gserviceaccount.com"
          };      
      return cert;
  }
  function getJWT() {
      var cert = getCert();
      var key = KEYUTIL.getKey(cert.private_key);
      var headers = { "alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT" };
      var issued = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);

      var claims = {
          "iss": cert.client_email,
          "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
          "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
          "exp": issued + 3600,
          "iat": issued
      };

      var jwt = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(headers.alg, headers, JSON.stringify(claims), key);
      return jwt;
  }
  ```
- When you test your code you should receive a json object back with an auth token. You can test your implementation like so:

  ```
  postJWT(getJWT(text), function(){
      let token = JSON.parse(response).access_token;
      //Do your api calls here using the token. 
      //Reuse the token for up to 1 hour.
  });
  ```

Here is an example successful json object with token:

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.c.ElkABZznrLNLK6ZAq2ybiH5lsRJpABE8p7MlZZJ0WCKcDNDv75lh-o1iRX__uMNUKSySiawm4YJGsbfqJH2JH61nRK6O2m0GJR7DgkEmo6ZlKtrvzke9C3xpwA",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

**Please note that this approach requires that the key/cert be accessible from your javascript environment. If this environment is public your api is vulnerable.**

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how to use this in combination with a call to google analytics api

Comment: @Elvira I've updated the code to reflect where you should place your api call. If you need help setting up an api call using a token ask a new question and tag me or link it here, so I can help. I'll try to keep an eye out for it.

Comment: I've successfully managed to follow the instructions above, and I am able to log in and retrieve a token for the service account. However when I try to fetch calendar data from gapi, I get an empty array. Anyone here who can help and give some advice? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222082/javascript-google-calender-gapi-service-account)

Comment: Are you able to read anything calendar or otherwise? Can you write to the calendar or other api? You may not have permission to the calendar, but I can't say definitively what your problem is.

Comment: Be sure to upvote the question and not just the answer if it helped you, so that others will be able to find this thread easier. Feel free to message me directly. Thanks!

Comment: To import jsrsasign, i have downloaded the .js file and added below three lines in getJWT() function:

    var imported = document.createElement('script');
    imported.src = 'jsrsasign-all-min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(imported);